# How to force "startx" at startup?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, display, startx

Sorry if I used wrong subject, but my problem is explained completely here: https://forum.armbian.com/topic/5561-how-to-configure-scriptbincustomfex-for-spi-lcd/?tab=comments#comment-42545

I did create .conf files within `etc/modprobe.d` and `etc/modules-loud.d` , also in `share/X11/xorg.conf.d` directories, and after booting system I can see my LCD turns on (only blank black screen), like when I ran this command:

```
sudo modprobe fbtft_device custom name=fb_ili9341 gpios=reset:1,dc:201,led:6 speed=16000000 rotate=90 bgr=1
```

But nothing more... I should run `startx' command manually to get a gray blank screen with a black mouse and right-click ability!

But I like this happens automatically after booting! I searched my OS docuements and found this:

```
script.bin/fex file

The settings in the [disp_init] section of the script.bin/fex file define the display output enabled at boot.

An example configuration for HDMI:

[disp_init]
disp_init_enable = 1
disp_mode = 0
screen0_output_type = 3
screen0_output_mode = 4
fb0_framebuffer_num = 2
fb0_format = 10
fb0_pixel_sequence = 0
fb0_scaler_mode_enable = 0

    disp_mode selects single-screen output or different dual screen modes. Generally this is 0, which means use screen0 with fb0 (one screen).
    screen0_output_type = 3 means HDMI output.
    screen0_output_mode selects the video/monitor mode to use (resolution and refresh rate). See the table in the Fex guide.
    fb0_framebuffer_num selects the number of buffers for fb0, generally you need 2 or more for video acceleration or Mali (3D), 3 is better.
    fb0_format and fb0_pixel_sequence determine the pixel format in the framebuffer. The above example (values of 10 and 0) selects the most common variant of 32bpp truecolor (ARGB).
    fb0_scaler_mode_enable selects whether the scaler should be enabled. Enabling it does not really scale pixels, it configures the scaler to scale pixels 1-to-1 which can fix screen refresh-related problems at 1080p resolution. See the section below.

Similar parameter are defined for screen1 (which is usually disabled in practice).
```

But I don't know how to change it? Also I know my LCD uses `fb8` as framebuffer.  Also my OS is armbian-5.30(Ubuntu server 16.04 ported for allwinner-h3 nanopi-m1 board)

Also there is a guide here but I couldn't understand it truely: http://linux-sunxi.org/Fex_Guide#spi_configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sunxi is not ubuntu. Just put `startx` command into `/etc/rc.local` to run at boot time.

Comment: Thank you Ipor!
But I have two questions: 1-What's script.bin? can I change it to make boot faster?
2-If I want to write a program in C++, and it starts at startup(like a kiosk linux), Should I put my program inside `/etc/rc.local` ?  How?