# Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory

Tags: xorg, display, images, x-server, gtk3

I have installed `libgtk-3-dev` and wrote and compiled this code successfully(without errors I mean):

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void destroy(void) {
  gtk_main_quit();
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
  GtkWidget* window;
  GtkWidget* image;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);


  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  image  = gtk_image_new_from_file(argv[1]);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT (window), "destroy",
             G_CALLBACK (destroy), NULL);

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), image);

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

But after trying to run the executable it says:

```
(process:5771): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(img:5771): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

I should say I use Ubuntu-server 16/04 and installed `xorg, xserver-xorg-video-fbdev, openbox` packages too. I have a gray blank screen with a black mouse and right-click menu after boot.

EDIT:
I used this command to connect to my board: `ssh m@192.168.1.7 -X` Then program worked and it opened the image by `./img 1.png` but in my laptop that I used for ssh! I liked to open the image in my board's LCD, not in my laptop!

Also it gives me this message in terminal:

```
(process:1909): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
```

> SOLUTION:I attached a keyboard to my board and opened it's terminal(by
>   right-click inside it's openbox window) and executed my program
>   successfully and it showed my picture in the SPI LCD!

Comment: @karel: Thanks Karel, but I tried the GTK official example and it didn't work too, and gave me the same error! 
I must emphasis that my code compiles without error too but when I try `./test 1.png` it gives me that error!

Comment: `./test 1.png` works perfectly on my computer so your code works OK, there must be some problem with the operating system, probably related to the gray blank screen with a black mouse and right-click menu after boot. If the code is OK and there is an OS problem then this question is on topic. For example the `Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory` error may be because you executed a command as root that didn't need to be executed as root.

Comment: @karel: here I said how did I run my display! I think the problem is here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401884/how-to-force-startx-at-startup

Comment: I used `startx` command inside `/etc/rc.local`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attached a keyboard to my board and opened it's terminal(by right-click inside it's openbox window) and executed my program successfully and it showed my picture in the SPI LCD!